# javascript: how to remove element on title

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, title

As the title, how can I remove a div on the html title using javascript or jquery framework?
I know it sounds weird but currently I'm working on a CMS template and the generate title has  around the title

`<title><div id="title">Title of the page</div></title>`

Any help appreciated

Comment: you want to get: <title>Title of the page</title> or  <title></title>?

Comment: I want <title>Title of the page</title>, and the content of the title will be dynamic. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("title").text($("<div/>").html($("title").text()).text());
```

Stores the (inappropriate) HTML text of the original title tag into a temporary div, then puts the plain-text content of the temporary div back into the title.

EDIT: Probably a better solution that works on IE6 as well:

```
document.title = $("<div/>").html(document.title).text();
```

Comment: @Bob - Make sure this works for you in IE (if needed). I don't think it does.

Comment: @patrick, you're right the previous code didn't work on IE, thanks for the update Sean. You're a legend!

Answer (score 1):

Do:

```
// get the title from the div and apply to the title tag and then remove div
$('div#title').parent().html($(this).text()).remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var tag = /(\<.*?\>)/g;
document.title = document.title.replace( tag, "" );
```

Comment: +1 - Cleaner than mine (deleted). Not sure why I didn't use `document.title` to get the text of the title. And works cross-browser unlike the others.

Comment: @Bob - This answer from yulerz will give you better performance.

Answer (score 0):

**<title>Title of the page</title>**
to strip the div tags

```
var title = document.getElementsByTagName("title")[0];
title.innerHTML = title.firstChild.innerHTML;
```

**or <title></title>**
If you want to remove the whole div

```
var title = document.getElementById("title");
title.parentNode.removeChild(title);
```

Comment: Neither of your solutions work for me. Which browsers did you test in?