# Remove a specific unnamed ul element from html with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to use javascript to search for an exact line of html and remove it without the element having a class or id?

For example I have a unordered list of items loading into the page from a source I have no control over and it looks a bit like this

```
<div class="content">
    <ul>
        <li class="thumb">
            <a href="#" title="something"><img src="http://img.png" alt="" ></a>
        </li>
        <li class="info">
            <ul>
                <li>something 1</li>
                <li><a href="#" title="something 1">Something 1</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <!-- I want to remove from here.. -->
    <ul>
        <li class="thumb">
            <a href="#" title="something 2"><img src="http://img.png" alt=""></a>     
        </li>
        <li class="info">
            <ul>
                <li>something 2</li>
                <li><a href="#" title="something 2">Something 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <!-- ..to here -->

    <ul>
        <li class="thumb">
            <a href="#" title="something 3"><img src="http://img.png" alt=""></a>
        </li>
        <li class="info">
            <ul>
                <li>something 3</li>
                <li><a href="#" title="something 3">Something 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>               
</div>
```

My goal is to use javascript (if possible) to remove the entire `<ul>` that contains `"Something 2"` , the  itself wont change at all but the order of the lists might.. so using css like:

```
.content ul:nth-child(2) {
    display:none;
}
```

isn't an option sadly. Also I have no ability to use PHP to do this either. Can something like this be done with javascript? and how?

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript: how to remove element on title](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3153611/javascript-how-to-remove-element-on-title)

Comment: @Alaeddine It's not a duplicate of that, it has to do with finding matching html on the page and removing it. not the document title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
   $("ul li a[title='something 2']").parent().parent().remove();
})
```

Comment: this worked perfectly! I really need to study up on javascript, this parent() function is great!

Comment: yeah...there are other functions too that are really great like parents(),closest() etc...